# Rails I18n add new locale file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine, rails-i18n

I am trying to add new file to

```
/home/user/Project/blog/config/locales/ru.yml
```

So, I do just right click no the locales folder and add file `ru.yml`

BUT `RubyMine` show me exeption:

```
Rails i18n locale file should have single root!
```

[image]

Should I do some additional actions?

Comment: Why is your file called `ry.yml` in the screenshot?

Comment: I just made typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is because you have two "root level" nodes in that .yml file.

```
ru:
  foo:
bad_root:
```

Also your file appears to be named `ry.yml` instead of your expected `ru.yml` not sure if that is what you intended.

Comment: Jared, ry. just typo. Could you please clarify what  does "root" mean? Is the locales files should have strong structure?

Comment: OMG! This text in the file 'space' sensitive. It is my fault.

Comment: Yup, only one thing can have zero spaces at the `root` and every level below that has to have two spaces to indent to the next level.

Comment: I see. Thank you!